# how to work with extension created in postgres in spring data jpa

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I am new to spring data jpa.

i have a legacy database , which i am trying to connect to via spring data jpa.

i have a certain extension created in postgres which is used for some of the columns in my tables

for e.g
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS citext WITH SCHEMA public;

this extension is created mostly for (case-insensitive text)

now when i try to map the tables using standard entity annotations, it gives me error, as its unable to understand this extension

The error i get is

g.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [domain_obj_nm] in table [attr_grp_defn]; found [citext (Types#OTHER)], but expecting [varchar(255) (Types#VARCHAR)]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1634)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at com.sas.mkt.example.app.Application.main(Application.java:43)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [domain_obj_nm] in table [attr_grp_defn]; found [citext (Types#OTHER)], but expecting [varchar(255) (Types#VARCHAR)]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:371)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1692)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1630)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [domain_obj_nm] in table [attr_grp_defn]; found [citext (Types#OTHER)], but expecting [varchar(255) (Types#VARCHAR)]

i want a way via annotations to solve this issue, its ok if it is treated just as text column.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is validating the schema on start-up as the ddl.auto property is set to validate.

You can either disable validation entirely or specify a column definition for the relevant `@Column`property which should allow the validation to pass:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#columnDefinition()

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "citext") //or "other"?
private String myField;
```

Note that the column definition only affects DDL operations i.e. schema creation or validation.

Disabling validation entirely depends on your set-up. In a spring-boot app for example you set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = false`